# Cannot set the style for input element when use create document

Tags: javascript, angular

I create one input element by this code:

```js
 self._hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
    self._hiddenInput.type = 'text';
    self._hiddenInput.width = self._width.toString();
    self._hiddenInput.height = self._height.toString();
    self._hiddenInput.style.position = 'absolute';
    self._hiddenInput.style.opacity = '0';
    self._hiddenInput.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    self._hiddenInput.style.zIndex = '0';
    // hide native blue text cursor on iOS
    self._hiddenInput.style.transform = 'scale(0)';
    self._hiddenInput.style.left = self._pointTextbox.x + 'px';
    self._hiddenInput.style.top = self._pointTextbox.y + 'px';
    self._hiddenInput.style.width = self._width + 'px';
    self._hiddenInput.style.height = self._height + 'px';

    // append this to document
    document.body.appendChild(self._hiddenInput);
```

But when I append this to the document it not have the width height like this:
[image: Input element]

I dont't know why this input cannot apply the style i have been set. Please help me.

Comment: What do `self._width.toString()` and `self._height.toString()` return?

Comment: This is the width and height i wanna to set style for this input sir.

Comment: If they return number, just append `px` to them, all dimensional properties must specify a unit, or else, they won't apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to set css:

```
self._hiddenInput.style.cssText = 'width:50px;height:300px;';
```